# getResources() returns null

Tags: java, eclipse

Using Eclipse IDE. The line:

```
getClass().getResource("/res/bitmaps/image.png");
```

returns `null`. I have created the `res` folder in the root of my project.

The code of interest is:

```
bImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/bitmaps/image.png"));
```

and it throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1378)
    at com.example.game.resource.Resources._loadImage(Resources.java:31)
    at com.example.game.GameComponent.<init>(GameComponent.java:19)
    at com.example.game.GameFrame.<init>(GameFrame.java:8)
    at com.example.game.GameFrame.main(GameFrame.java:13)
```

Any help?

Comment: What directory structure do you have?

Comment: The root folder of my project contains the `src` and the `res` folders. The `res` folder contains the `bitmaps` folder which contains `image.png`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/drawable/image.png"));
```

Make sure res folder is in class path, verify using project properties > Java build Path > Source tab. If not in class path, can add via **Add Folder..** button on the right.

Comment: Resolved. The solution was to add the `res` folder to the build path and to get the resource with the string `"/bitmaps/image.png"`

Answer (score 1):

You say the resource is in "the root of my project" - is it that folder in your build path? You need to have it in your build path so that Eclipse will copy it to the output directory (`bin` by default).

Answer (score 1):

```
getClass().getResource("/res/drawable/image.png");
```

You should give the path of the folder in which **image.png** exists

Comment: The `res` folder contains the `bitmaps` folder which contains the `image.png` file.

Comment: @mneri It works for me, I think you have some buildpath problem.

Comment: I think so. The root of my project contains the `src` folder and the `res` folder. May I have to add the `res` folder to the build path? How?

Comment: @mneri well I am not sure but you can try, Right click on your project folder, then go to the Build path, select link Source and do as asked.

Answer (score 0):

If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.

Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form: 
package_name/name

Where the package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').